# Create Outlook calendar event with Python

Tags: python, outlook, icalendar

How would you create a calendar event in Outlook from Python without requiring the user to manually accept an event invite?

I've seen several examples of creating calendar events by [emailing ical attachments](http://www.baryudin.com/blog/sending-outlook-appointments-python.html). However, these all require the user to view the email and approve the event.

I'm developing a small Django application that has some event integration, and when a user creates a "todo" or "reminder" record, they want an event to immediately appear in their Outlook calendar. Emailing them the ical file accomplishes that, but it adds the redundant work of requiring that they approve the event they just created. Is there a way around that?

Also, I'm on a Linux platform, so connecting to Outlook through some sort of special Microsoft VB component probably won't work.

Comment: I have used [PyExcahnge][1] to interact with an outlook exchange server to setup appointments in my own calender. I will still have to login and the code will use my credentials. I dont know if this is what you are looking for. Can you give more details on what kind of server is your outlook talking to?

  [1]: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyexchange/0.4.1

Comment: @Ashwin, Yeah, that's actually what I'm looking for. Requiring the user's credentials is probably what I'll need, but that's acceptable for my app.

Comment: If you are talking to an exchange server, then you can pretty much do anything using pyexchange. You can find the documentation here: https://pyexchange.readthedocs.org/en/latest/